# Custom template for product detail page is blank - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

This is sample url-https://www.inoventary.com/product/ipega-wireless-bluetooth-gamepad/

single product page on woocommerce store is showing only header and footer , not showing product or single product page template .

Log Error -2018-06-12T17:15:39+00:00 CRITICAL Call to undefined function dhvc_woo_get_product_formatted_name()

I don't know how to fix , your answer is very much appreciated

Comment: restore the file from woocommerce plugin templates and check if its working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your theme is overriding default woocommerce template and there is some function being used which is not found.
You can do following:

1. Take fresh copy of single-product folder from wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates and upload that in your theme's woocommerce folder
2. Looking at name of undefined function, it shows that this function might have been there only for formatting product title, so if you don't want to follow step 1 then just trace this function in your code and comment it out.

Let me know if it helps